# Getting permalink of selected CPT item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created some custom fields within the product detail pages of WooCommerce. One of the fields is a "post_checkboxes" type (to select the desired author of the product). I want to link the author text to the correct Author detail page (another custom post type).

When i try to retrieve the desired URL it echoes nothing:

```
<?php echo get_permalink(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_boekinfo_auteurnew", true)); ?>
```

Within other websites i created, this method works. The difference is I am trying to retrieve this url from within a woocommerce product page (content-single-product.php). I think it has something to do with that. Do you guys have any clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start dumping out all of your variables to make sure they contain what you expect. Do a `var_dump` on the `$post` and then check the database looking for post meta with that post's ID. Dump the value of `get_post_meta` and check that with what is in the database. Then dump the `get_permalink` call. Just validate every step to check for small mistakes.

Comment: It didn't work in the end, but within the loop it did, so solved it that way. Dumps gave me false and NULL errors.

Comment: You should write out an answer detailing how you solved it in case anyone else runs into a similar issue and finds this question.